# How to fix UI to Light mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've been cracking  my head to fix my app to work in Light Mode even when user changes phones UI to Dark Mode ie I want this pic layout to be fixed in [This Light Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJazg.png)
But when I select Dark Mode in my phone all I get is[This Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpBn5.png)and it looks really bad.

This is what my styles file look like

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've literally tried everything like

```
> android:forceDarkAllowed="false" (In xml File)
> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()  (In Kotlin file)
> val currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK  (In Kt file)
```

Help me find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just want a light theme? You're using a dark one, change it to this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```